# Connection rejected: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding)

Tags: firebird, jaybird, dbeaver

When I try to connect to a Firebird database with dbeaver this error is shown:

[image]

> Connection rejected: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding). Please specify a connection character set (eg property charSet=utf-8) or consult the Jaybird documentation for more information

Answer (score 3):

Edit Connection -> Driver properties -> Add new property
lc_ctype = .... (example WIN1252,UTF-8,UNICODE,...)

https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/community/ppts/fbcon11/FbCon2011-Charsets-Heymann.pdf

Comment: Please explain little about your answer here.

Answer (score 1):

The error says you "Please specify a connection character set" - and that is what you have to do.

Open DBeaver configuration, find the `connection string` or how it is called in DBeaver, and add any one of the connection encoding parameters with the value you want to the connection URI you set in DBeaver.

See [section 3.2 in the Jaybird FAQ](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#character-sets):

> Jaybird provides two connection properties to specify the connection
>   character set:
>
> - `charSet` with a Java character set name (alias: `localEncoding`)
>
>   The Java character set name must map to an equivalent Firebird character set.
> - `encoding` with a Firebird character set name (alias: `encoding`[*sic, should be `lc_ctype`*])
>
>   The Firebird character set name - with the exception of `NONE` must map to an equivalent Java character set.
>
> For most applications, use only one of these two properties.

For the specifics of this error see [section 3.2.3 in the FAQ](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#how-can-i-solve-the-error-connection-rejected-no-connection-character-set-specified).

Answer (score -1):

I had to install a past jaybird.jar version 2.2.13 of driver connection of Firebird to fix this problem.

Comment: past jaybir .jar, sorry... version 2.2.13

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) sections to see how this site works.

Comment: Don't use comments - better use the **edit** link to add some additional information (see my edit).